# UI-Router v0.2.13 versus v0.2.15 ui-view layout only shows after double click in v0.2.15

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Today i spent a whole day figuring out what was going wrong. For some reason when i click on `app.main.foo` and using version 0.2.13 of UI-Router this example works. But the exact same thing with version 0.2.15 i have to double click before my header and sidebar are loaded. I could simply use version 0.2.13 as this would fix my problem but is this a know issue or has somethings change since the latest version. This is my demo application :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>

<head>

    <!--@version v1.4.7-->
    <script src="angular.js"></script>

    <!--@version v0.2.15
    Header and side bar shows only after double clicking app.main.foo
    <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    -->

    <!--Best version for this example -->
    <script
            src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.login">app.login</a>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.main">app.main</a>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.main.foo">app.main.foo</a>       
</ul>

<div ui-view=""></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/login.html">
    <div>
        Login view
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/sidebar.html">
    <div>
        <h3>SideBar View1</h3>
        <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/main.html">
        <h3>Main View</h3>

</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/header.html">
        <h3>Header View</h3>
</script>



<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/layout.html">
        <h2>Layout View</h2>
            <div ui-view="header"></div>
            <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

     angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])

}());
```

route.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(routesConfig);

    routesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function routesConfig( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/',
                template: '<ui-view/>'
            })
            .state('app.login', {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'login',
                url: ''
            })
            .state('app.main', {
                url: 'room',
                templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
            })
            .state('app.main.foo', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/header.html'

                    },
                    'sidebar': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/sidebar.html'

                    },
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
                    }
                }
            });

    }
})();
```